# Getting error when building app in Gitlab CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: android, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I have been trying to build the app in pipeline to run just unit tests but I am getting error which i cannot find anywhere else can you guys look and tell me what I an doing wrong here.

here is what I am getting as an error.

```html
Preparing to unpack .../lib32z1_1%3a1.2.11.dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lib32z1 (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2) ...
Setting up libc6-i386 (2.31-13+deb11u2) ...
Setting up lib32z1 (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2) ...
Setting up lib32gcc-s1 (10.2.1-6) ...
Setting up lib32stdc++6 (10.2.1-6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u2) $ wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```html
image: openjdk:11-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "31"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "32.0.0"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "7583922"

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
  - unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
  - set +o pipefail
  - yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
  - set -o pipefail

stages:
  - build
  - test

lintDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :app:lintDebug -PbuildDir=lint

assembleDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/

debugTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :app:testDebug
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that URL you are constructing here .. does not exist anymore .. hence fails

```
wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\Sayan> curl https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-7583922.zip
curl :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
```